# Error recuperando variable en JQuery

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Cuando establezco la fecha en el  `#datetimepicker1` manualmente como en el código, la pone bien. Pero cuando sustituyo la fecha por el valor de `id`, id está en blanco, y no establece. (el id del elemento que se le dio clic es una fecha al estilo 20-10-2018). Sin embajo id en el alert aparece como una fecha del tipo 20-10-2018. Me estoy rompiendo la cabeza con eso, pensando pasar la variable por ajax para php, y un monton de cosas que no me parecen limpias.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var id;
    $(".cell").dblclick(function(e){
        id = e.target.id;
        $('#ModalReserva').modal('toggle'); 
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({date: '9-10-2018'});
        alert (id);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo general el `datePicker` es un elemento para seleccionar fechas. Otra cosa es que quieras actualizarlo desde **otro input** (lo cual sería algo extraño pero bueno, todo es posible).

Si quieres recuperar la fecha seleccionada, tienes que crear en el `datepicker` una función `onSelect`, la cual recibirá del mismo elemento la fecha en parámetro.

Por ejemplo:

```js
$("#myDatePicker").datepicker({
    /*Formato deseado en la salida*/
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    onSelect: function (date) {
        console.log(date);
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
  <p>Fecha: <input type="text" id="myDatePicker" readonly /></p>
```

---

#### EDICIÓN

Veamos algo parecido a lo que dices que tienes: una tabla donde por cada celda hay una fecha concreta.

Si la información se encuentra en el `id` de cada celda (o en otra parte). No tiene ningún sentido abrir un `datepicker` para seleccionar algo que ya conoces.

Este código te muestra cómo al hacer clic sobre cualquier celda obtienes el valor que hay en su atributo `id`. Puedes trabajar con ese valor, sin necesidad de obligar al usuario a establecer de nuevo la fecha. En este caso tu propia tabla hace la misma función que haría un `datepicker`:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".table td").forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('click', getDate, false);
});

function getDate() {
  var theDate = this.id;
  console.log(theDate);
  alert(theDate);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class="table is-bordered">
  <tr>
    <td id="20180101">1</td>
    <td id="20180102">2</td>
    <td id="20180103">3</td>
    <td id="20180104">4</td>
    <td id="20180105">5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hola Cedano, imagino que no me expliqué bien.

Yo tengo varias celdas de una tabla, cada una con un id diferente, y que dicho id no es mas que una fecha al estilo 10-12-2018. 

Ese datapicker esta en un formulario modal, y lo que quiero es que cuando yo de doble clic en esa celda, se abra el formulario modal (cosa que ya hace), pero que el datapicker del formulario modal, tenga como fecha el id del td que se le dio clic. 

Cuando yo establezco la fecha manualmente, el lo hace bien, solo si pongo como variable id en vez de poner la fecha manual, es que no funciona.

Comment: Ahora sí se entiende. No te explicaste con tanta claridad en la pregunta. Cuando disponga de tiempo podré ayudarte con esto si otra persona ya no lo ha hecho. Aunque es extraño querer abrir un datepicker en base a lo que se escriba en una celda. ¿Con qué finalidad quieres hacer eso?

Comment: Es un calendario que se crea al vuelo, en el momento que se esta cargando, y cada celda de la tabla coincide con la fecha que muestra el encabezado de la tabla. Como si fuera una especie de agenda, solo que cuando abri el modal para escribir un nuevo evento, no tiene sentido colocar la fecha de inicio si ya di clic en esa fecha de la tabla.

Comment: A ver si puedo entender @SergioCristiá. Cuando haces clic en una de esas celdas con una fecha, ¿para qué quieres mostrar el datepicker? ¿es con la intención de cambiar esa fecha (la que existe en la celda) por otra? Es que no logro captar cuál es la lógica que estás siguiendo...

Comment: Me explico nuevamente. Tengo un calendario.    Con los dias 1 2 3 4 5 6 .... Ese calendario es una tabla, como cualquier calendario. Yo agrego en determinado dia un evento. Tengo un formulário para anhadir eventos, donde pongo fecha de entrada y salida. Este formulario se abre al dar clic en cualquiera de las celdas de la tabla, cuyas celdas tienen en el id el dia mes y anho que estan mostrando del calendário, generado con php. Cuando abro el formulário en vez de tener que escribir la fecha quiero que el datapicker coja la fecha que esta guardada en el id de la celda. quiero cambiar el datapic

Comment: @SergioCristiá pero si ya tienes la fecha en la celda que seleccionaste, ¿de qué te sirve el datepicker? Puedes tomar el valor de la celda, que será la fecha que necesitas. El datepicker es útil cuando no conoces ninguna fecha, en este caso la fecha ya se conoce: es el valor de esa celda que seleccionaste. No es algo lógico que quieras usar de nuevo el datepicker para eso.

Comment: @SergioCristiá revisa la edición de la respuesta, al final de la misma pongo un código de ejemplo de lo que afirmo en mi anterior comentario...